# multiply all elements in a list of tuples for elements in a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I know it might sound easy but that problem is making me struggle.

I have a list of tuple as

```
[(0,1),(3,4)]
```

And I want to multiply all its values for all the values in a list like

```
[ 1, 2, 3]
```

So That in this case I will get a new list (nested) of tuples:

```
[[(0,1),(0,2),(0,3)],[(3,4),(6,8),(9,12)]]
```

How can I obtain this result?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Also see Stack Overflow guidance on [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is unacceptable, and is likely a violation of your school's academic honesty policies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a list comprehension :

```
tuples = [(0,1),(3,4)]
multipliers = [1, 2, 3]

results = [[(t[0]*m, t[1]*m) for m in multipliers] for t in tuples]
```

Answer (score 0):

nested loops.

```
result = []
for t in tuples:
    for m in multipliers:
        result.append( (t[0]*m, t[1]*m) )

print(result)
```

gives:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (3, 4), (6, 8), (9, 12)]
```

This is a list of tuples (the inner list).